# Why does setTimeout inside runOutsideAngular callback skip change detection for the observable, even if markForCheck is called manually?

Tags: angular, settimeout, angular2-changedetection, zonejs, async-pipe

I've noticed a strange behavior of change detection in Angular. When Observable updated as in the example, change detection not triggered for some reason.

The key here is `setTimeout` called inside the callback, if you remove it, change detection will work fine. `markForCheck` which inside `AsyncPipe` also called as it should.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template:
    '<button (click)="click()">Trigger</button> <br> {{value$ | async}}',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class AppComponent {
  readonly value$ = new BehaviorSubject(1);

  constructor(
    private readonly zone: NgZone,
  ) {}

  click() {
    this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {

      setTimeout(() => {
        this.value$.next(this.value$.value + 1);
        console.log(`Change (Should be ${this.value$.value})`);
      });

    });
  }
}
```

[StackBlits example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-j2xzse?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

[StackBlitz with async pipe debug example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-z6qiy5?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Why are you doing that though

Comment: "Why does setTimeout inside runOutsideAngular callback skip change detection for the observable", that's the idea of putting logic into `runOutsideOfAngular`... there is no change detection in there, is outside of `zone.js`... after you do whatever logic in there, in order to add it to the zone, you need to add `this.zone.run()`

Comment: Why would you add logic into `runOutsideAngular` if you need change detection in there.. for that, just do your logic without `NgZone`?

Comment: Because one of our external libraries uses `runOutsideAngular` (I don't know why) and potentially puts some observable mutation at the end of the event loop. As a result, this leads to the behavior that I described in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens:

The click triggers a CD cycle and marks the OnPush component to be checked. Timeout is started. Component is checked for changes, but the value did not change yet and so the UI is not updated. CD cycle is done.

Timeout elapses. It does not trigger another CD cycle, because it is inside `runOutsideAngular`. Value is nexted. Async pipe calls `markForCheck`, but this does not have any visible effect until another CD cycle is triggered, e.g. by clicking the button another time.

If `setTimeout` is removed, the value is nexted in the same CD cycle that has been triggered by the button click, and the UI will be updated.

If `runOutsideAngular` is removed, the elapsing timeout triggers a new CD cycle, the component will be checked for changes because the async pipe called `markForCheck`, and the UI will be updated.

Comment: Refreshed my memory on `markForCheck`, thank you very much!